# How do I save user input in ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms

**my project**

[image]

I was wondering how to save the User input in a `ListView` and prevent it from disappearing when I go to another Form

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReview.Text))
    return;

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(txtName.Text);
    item.SubItems.Add(txtReview.Text);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
    txtName.Clear();
    txtReview.Clear();
```

Comment: Are you using a database?

Comment: no sir. in my class project, i can only use textfile as local save since its small project

Comment: The relevant part is the code that opens another Form. Do you close the Form where you just inserted the User Input? Before saving the data? Or the data is saved but you don't know how to bring it back?

Comment: i want to close the form and be able to save it and also be able to bring it back when i go back to the form

Comment: Are you closing the your current form while going to other form? If yes, your data must not be stored in code behind of form, instead it should be stored in Model class (this way it will not be lost form memory). And on load method of the form you should re-populate your list view with data. If you are not closing the form (or just hiding it), you should not be facing the problem.

Comment: @SeanMai i was preparing working example for you. but i guess you don't need it anymore (atleast your comment shows that). Now I too think trying to help you was waste of time.

Comment: it was meant to jimin not you amit but if you take it as personal then fine you dont have to waste your time here

Comment: @Amit  I saw your comment and I though he said something. I didn't see his. But if my wording caused a misundertanding, I'm sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

As far I got your concern! You have a form in which you are adding a reviews. You are closing it soon after adding review. But you want all previous reviews when you visit that form again.

you cannot use database (it certainly would have been easiest way to do though), but you are allowed to use file system (you said text files, i'm assuming serialization too)

But reading and writing files on every now and then is costly process, I would recommend you keep data in memory cache (insert new reviews, update and delete them if there may such option). While closing an application, you store last updated copy into file and while starting software you read that file to get last updated copy of data.
***(this way of storing data on closing software can cause data loss when software crash or stopped abnormally. but as it is class project, i would not worry much about that. however you can always use low priority thread to store data periodically)***

*For this approach, I would recommend to implement MVVM architecture*
At least you should create a class which store all the data statically 
(why static? it is an interesting question and i m leaving it on you to find out the answer)

Example code For Model:

```
public class Model
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Review> ReviewData;
    //this method should be called at application startup.
    public static void SetModel()
    {
        //Desrialize lastly saved file, I'm just initializing it with new 
        ReviewData = new Dictionary<string, Review>();
    }
    public static void AddReview(string movie, string reviewerName, string review)
    {
        if (!ReviewData.ContainsKey(movie + "-" + reviewerName))
        {
            ReviewData.Add(movie + "-" + reviewerName, new Review(reviewerName, reviewerName));
        }
    }
}

public class Review
{
    public string reviewerName;
    public string review;
    public Review(string reviewerName, string review)
    {
        this.reviewerName = reviewerName;
        this.review = review;
    }
}
```

Example Code for Add review form:

```
    private void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReview.Text))
            return;
        //First we should set Model data
        Model.AddReview("moive1", txtName.Text, txtReview.Text);
        LoadListView();
    }

    private void AddReviewForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadListView();
    }

    private void LoadListView()
    {
        listView1.Clear();
        foreach (string reviewKey in Model.ReviewData.Keys)
        {
            Review review = Model.ReviewData[reviewKey];
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(review.reviewerName);
            item.SubItems.Add(review.review);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

And last thing, while closing entire application, store lastly updated copy of `Model.ReviewData` (Serialize it).